# Batch file run through windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, automation, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a Task Scheduler in windows to run a `batch` file. This batch file in turn is calling a `cmd` file. The cmd file is expecting some user input. Could you please let me know how I can provide input to this automatic process?

The message being shown is as follows:

```
[input] Where is your product view ?
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... how I can provide input to this automatic process?

Suppose `myCmd.cmd` contains next line:

```
set /p "input=[input] Where is your product view ?"
```

Create file `myInput.txt` with appropriate answer as follows:

```
here is my product view
```

and in your batch file use `<` [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) as follows:

```
call myCmd.cmd<myInput.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing it like this:

```
ECHO Where is your product view ?
SET /p input=
```

So then you could simply set the `input` variable from a parameter instead:

```
SET input=%*
```

This would get the parameters when calling the BATCH-file. `file.bat "Here is my product view."`